# What is the difference between ‘classical’ and ‘non-classical’ pathogen resistance genes in plants?

Tags: genetics, terminology, immunity, parasitism

I have stumbled across a mention of classical resistance genes against pests in plants, however the classification seems a bit vague.

What would be classified as classical resistance genes and what as non-classical in plants?

Edit:

Found it here:

> 'For example, the identification of classical plant resistant genes in
> Arabidopsis and other model dicots facilitated the successful cloning
> of multiple wheat rust resistant genes (Ellis et al., 2014; Wulff and
> Moscou, 2014).'

- Schwessinger, Benjamin, et al. "Focus issue on plant immunity: from
  model systems to crop species." Frontiers in plant science 6 (2015):
  195.

Comment: Where have you stumbled across the mention, and what was said about it?

Comment: @BryanKrause i originally encountered it at a conference but then also found it here:

Schwessinger, Benjamin, et al. "Focus issue on plant immunity: from model systems to crop species." Frontiers in plant science 6 (2015): 195.

'For example, the identification of classical plant resistant genes in Arabidopsis and other model dicots facilitated the successful cloning of multiple wheat rust resistant genes (Ellis et al., 2014; Wulff and Moscou, 2014). '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited to reflect that the reference is to classic *genes* rather than to classic *immunity*.

Note that this is not a formal definition but rather an informal way of talking about the state of the scientific literature: "classic" or "classical" is a way of referring to the first-described, standard, or most familiar example of a phenomenon.

**The term "classic" has no biological salience, but rather has salience for the history of science and what is in textbooks (e.g. the necessarily subjective human perception of nature).**

See e.g. [this blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/03/27/classical-science/) discussing this loose way of writing.